# aws s3 AccessDenied when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a python code to use pandas to read s3 files located at

```
s3://bucket_name/table_name/file.parquet
```

If I provide the pull path with file name like above, my python works.
But if I provide the directory path as the prefix to list all objects and then get each object, I get the access denied error:

```
bucket=bucket_name
key=table_name/
objects=s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket,Prefix=key)['Contents']
print(objects)
dfs=[]
for obj in objects:
    file_key=obj['Key']
    obj=s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=file_key)
    df_single=pd.read_parquet(BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
    dfs.append(df_single)
df=pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

I got the error in the title.

I checked the IAM policy for the bucket. we allow for s3.ListBucket and s3.getObject for the bucket `"s3://bucket_name*/*"`

**UPDATE**

updated the policy by adding the resource without '/*' as shown below.
and attached this policy to the role that I use as the executing role of the lambda function (which runs the script)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:GetBucketTagging",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:BypassGovernanceRetention",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner",
                "s3:DescribeJob",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
                "s3:DeleteAccessPointPolicy",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutAccessPointPolicy",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:PutStorageLensConfiguration",
                "s3:CreateJob"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

run the script:

```
s3_resource=boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    print(obj.key)
```

get the error

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

Comment: Is `s3://bucket_name*/*` a typo or is that what you actually have in the IAM policy?

Comment: that's what we have in IAM policy. why do you think it's a typo?

Comment: It's unusual to wildcard a bucket name.

Comment: Why are you attempting a `GetObject` operation on a directory? Can you show us your actual code?

Comment: Do you have permission to see whether objects exist? You probably get a 403 instead of 404 when you access a nonexistent object, if you aren't allowed to know whether it exists or not.

Comment: You should use `ListObjects` to retrieve the content of a specific prefix and add a statement in the policy for the bucket-level operation.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, because that directory contains multiple parquet files, I need to list all the parquet file first, then get each object and put it into one dataframe. my origin question has been edited

Comment: @lpizzinidev, I updated my question with sample code, I do listObjects first, and I have both listbucket and getobject permission. it works fine when I getobject on single file in another folder within the same bucket.

Comment: For a start, could you please change `bucket_name*/*"` to `bucket_name/*"` otherwise it will only work on an object inside a directory. Not sure if that is causing the problem, but it is normal practice.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I changed bucket_name*/* to bucket_name/*. still no luck.

Comment: This is lambda function. could this be missing a specific Lambda access policy?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `ListBucket` requires permissions on the bucket (without `/*`) while `GetObject` applies at the **object level** and can use `*` wildcards.

Also, if you are granting access to an IAM User or IAM Role in the same AWS Account, it is better to **grant permissions via an IAM Policy** on the IAM User/Role instead of using a Bucket Policy.

This IAM Policy can be **applied to the IAM User/IAM Role** and grant access to the whole bucket to that user:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME"
        },
        {
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you were to use a **Bucket Policy** (not advisable), you would need to add a `Principal` to identify who receives access:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME",
            "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/USERNAME"
        },
        {
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*",
            "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/USERNAME"
        }
    ]
}
```

These policies can be further restricted to only grant access to a specific directory if desired. See: [Bucket policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html)

Comment: thanks @JohnRotenstein, I did what you suggested. still got the same error. I provided the update in my post.

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created a new Amazon S3 bucket with default settings
- Uploaded a few files to the bucket, with default settings
- Created a new IAM User and added an **inline policy** (substituting `BUCKET-NAME` for the actual bucket name):

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME"
        },
        {
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- Created an **Access Key + Secret Key** for this user in the IAM Console and stored the credentials using `aws configure --profile stack`
- Tested with `aws s3 ls --profile stack` -- it **successfully listed** the contents of my bucket
- Tested with a different bucket name -- was not able to list the bucket (as expected)
- Ran this Python code (substituting `my-bucket-name` for the actual bucket name):

```py
import boto3

BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket-name'

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='stack')
s3_resource = session.resource('s3')

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    print(obj.key)
```

- It **successfully listed the objects** I previously uploaded to the bucket

If your results are different, you might want to compare the above steps to what you have done.